# Understanding the definition of Uniform Absolute Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, uniform-convergence

The definition of uniform absolute convergence given here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Uniform_Absolute_Convergence states that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly absolutely if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|f_n\|$ converges uniformly.

I am a bit confused here by the taking of the norm of $f_n$ in the definition. The maps $f_n: S \rightarrow V$ map into the vector space, but the function itself is not in the vector space. So how come we can take the norm of the function? I.e. what does it mean to take the norm here?

Also the definition on wikipedia on the other hand is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges uniformly absolutely if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f_n(x)|$ is uniformly convergent. This makes more sense to me, as in this case, the definition just says that the series of the modulus of functions converges uniformly. I am not sure how to unify the two definitions.

My notes in real analysis introduce the same notation as the proofwiki definition, that is that we have uniform absolute convergence if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|f_n\|_{C(i)} < \infty$. Unfortunately, in the real analysis course we were told this was just a useful piece of notation that meant taking the supremum. The details were meant to be filled in during later courses in analysis. However now in Fourier analysis we are using the notation in more contexts, but I haven't actually been able to pick up on what it really means.

Comment: By $\lVert f_n\rVert$ they mean the function $x \mapsto \lVert f_n(x)\rVert$. That's not an unusual notation, but of course in the given setting there's the possibility of confusing it with the norm of $f_n$ in some function space, so it would have been better if they had written "$\sum \lVert f_n(x)\rVert$ converges uniformly".

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for the help; I'm unfortunately not seeing how this works. If they mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ||f_n(x)||$, then that means that this series converges uniformly by definition. But if it's evaluated at a specific point $x \in I$, where $I$ is the domain of the functions, then isn't that just a series of real numbers? If that's true how do we fit in the notion of uniform convergence?

Comment: "If they mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|f_n(x)\|$, then that means that this series converges uniformly by definition." (tip: $\|$ is `\|`) - what are you talking about? That has nothing to do with uniform convergence, which is why the definition then explicitly requires $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|f_n(x)\|$ to converge uniformly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In finite dimensions, all norms on a vector space are equivalent. Thus we tend to stick with the well-understood Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^n$, occasionally pulling out the sup or taxicab norms when computationally convenient.

But most function spaces are infinite-dimensional, which means norms finally have enough freedom to disagree with each other. And the thing is, there are several different norms that are useful. And when as here, we are talking about several possible spaces, each with its own norm, it becomes confusing which norm is being referred to.

There are only two notations for norms that are so widely used that an author can use them without explaining. These are:

- $\|\cdot\|_V$ is *the* norm on the space $V$. You can only use it when in context you've already defined a particular norm on $V$. Presumably, your professor had already mentioned they were using the sumpremum norm on $C(i)$ (maybe $C(I)$, where $I = [0,1]$?).
- $\|\cdot\|_p$, where $p$ is any real number $\ge 1$, or $p = \infty$. For $p < \infty$, these refer to the function norms $$\|f\|_p := \left[\int_M |f|^p\,d\mu\right]^{1/p}$$ defined for  functions $f$ on some measure space $M$ for which $|f|^p$ is integrable. $\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{x \in M} |f(x)|$, and is given that notation because $\lim_{p \to \infty} \|f\|_p = \|f\|_\infty$

In specialized fields of mathematics, there are some other notations that are well-known in that field, and may be used when speaking to those well-versed in the field. But when speaking to a wider mathematically inclined audience, the notations above are the only ones that can safely be used without explanation. And of course even then, there will always be a few novices who might need an introduction.

---

The tip-off that Daniel Fischer is correct about the intent here is the definition specifies that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|f_n\|$ must converge *uniformly*.  If $\|f_n\|$ meant the supremum norm of $f_n$, then the series would be a sum of real numbers, and talking about "uniform" convergence makes no sense. Uniform with respect to what? In order to talk about uniform convergence, $\sum \|f_n\|$ must be a sum of functions. The interpretation that makes $\|f_n\|$ a function is that it means the function $$\|f_n\| : S \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto \|f_n(x)\|$$

Comment: Thank you your answer! I am still struggling with a few points. Specifically in your last paragraph, I think I understand what you're saying up till the end. I.e. that the definition can't refer to the sup norm, because otherwise it doesn't make sense to talk about uniform convergence because now we just have a series of real numbers.

Comment: But the things I am still confused by are that in our real analysis course, we were told that by definition, the $\| f_n\|_{C(I)} = sup | f_n|$ But then this definition is exactly a sequence of real numbers and I'm stuck again! The second thing is I am not quite sure what the very last equation means. And I end up still being unsure what norm is being used in the proofwiki definition. In particular, with the notation $\| f_n(x)\|$. I don't understand this because isn't $f_n(x)$ a value rather than an element of the sequence?

Comment: First, as I said in my post, $\|f_n\|_{C(I)}$ only meant the sup norm because your professor defined it to be that in your course. There are other norms that may be placed on $C(I)$, so when reading material from other sources, you should not just expect them to mean the same thing. But second, we are discussing $\|f_n\|$, not $\|f_n\|_{C(I)}$, so it is moot what the latter notation means. Because $\|f_n\|$ is ambiguous, ProofWiki should have made its meaning explicit. But they didn't, so we have to deduce it. Your idea doesn't work, which means the idea is **wrong**. Stop going back to it.

Comment: $\|f_n\| : S \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto \|f_n(x)\|$ is not an "equation" (notice the complete lack of an "$=$" sign within it). It is a common notation for defining functions: In $$F : A \to B : x \mapsto \text{ (expression)}$$ $F$ is the label for the function, $A$ is the domain of $F$, $B$ is the codomain (the set where $F$ takes its values), $x$ is a variable representing an element of $A$, and $\text{(expression)}$ is some means of specifying what $F(x)$ should be.

Comment: So yes, for each $x, f_n(x)$ and $\|f_n(x)\|$ are just values, as is $\sum \|f_n(x)\|$. But note that "for each $x$". You put a value of $x$ in, and each of them gives you another value out. You put same $x$ back in, and each gives the same other value back out. If you put a different $x$ in, you may get the same or a different value back out. This is what a *function* is. $\|f_n(x)\|$ is a sequence of values for a fixed $x$, But when $x$ varies, it defines a function.